# Save Android Studio settings before uninstall to update

Tags: android-studio

I'm relatively new to Android app development. When I started I installed Android Studio, and the application was the one that notified me that there was an update. To update, you only had to make a few clicks and Android Studio updated itself.

I recently installed Android Studio on another PC and noticed that the LogCat was different. Then I realized that the Android Studio on my PC was outdated.

Now, to update it I have to download an installer and install it from scratch, it is no longer an update. To install it I cannot use the default path since it is the previous version. So in order not to have 2 IDEs installed I have to uninstall the old version.

The version of Android Studio that I have installed is this:

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1 
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 18,2022
```

On Windows machine.

My question is if I uninstall Android Studio, do I lose all the settings I have? Emulators, coding style,... Do I have to save some configuration folder so I don't have to redo everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before uninstalling, you can export your settings by selecting `File > Export Settings...` in Android Studio.

Which you may import into Android Studio later on.

You can copy the image files from the AVD folder in your Android Studio installation directory, which is normally found in the `/.android/avd/` folder, to export your emulator images.

Comment: In my Android Studio the options are in File > Manage ID Settings menu.